# Fastest way to get a TouchEvents in a new Acitivity

Tags: android, android-activity, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I want to get a TouchEvent in an Activity as quick as possible after the Activity was created/started.
I know three options:

1. with onClick in layout.xml
2. with OnClick/TouchListener
3. OnTouchEvent method.

What I want to know is, is there one that is faster than the others?

Comment: i mean something like which one will be the first to react on a TouchEvent when/after the activity is started/created. i'm thinking about to implement a double-click on a widget with that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one link that shows all types of onClickListner of the android and also their pros and cons. It also have examples of all the methods also. This might be helpful to you.

http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/

Thanks..